# Apache server-status: allow access only from one subdomain on same IP

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I'm configuring server-status and get 404 error. I need allow access to `server-status` only from site subdomain on same IP. I put `server-status` location to virtualhost config, but it's not working.

If I put `location` into `httpd.conf`, server-status works on all subdomains.

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8082
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8082>
    ServerName tools.sitename.ru
    RPAFenable On
    RPAFsethostname Off
    RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1
    #    RPAFheader X-Real-IP
#    AllowOverride All
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tools.sitename

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html default.asp index.cgi
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/tools.sitename.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/tools.sitename.access.log common

    <Location /server-info>
        SetHandler server-info
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes - dont I remember my hair-pulling sessions when I encountered this a while back then.   Use double quote when identifying `<location />`

For example - in my apache2 virtual hosting, similar setup as yours:

```
 <Location "/">
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from all
    </Location>
```

I noticed that double quote marks is used for  but not others as needed.  But, that's how I beat Apache to get working.  EDIT: After checking, it appears that I also used double quote marks for `<directory "/var/www">` as well.  Strangely enough, but, that's how I get Apache to work.